# Making Web page show from the top

Tags: jquery, wordpress, web, iframe, loading

I have a web page using wordpress.

https://nas.cloudbusinessportal.com/wordpress/london-ice-cream

this page has an embedded iframe

the problem is the embedded iframe cause the web page to focus in middle instead of the top.

Any suggestions?

I tried to add html to the bottom using

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
</script>
```

but it does not work.

my guess is that the main page is loaded first and the Html code (although below the embedded material) is before the iframe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `window.onbeforeunload` event to scroll to top.

#### Try below Code

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

```css
div {
    height: 500px;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">Reload</a>
<div>2</div>
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">Reload</a>
<div>3</div>
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">Reload</a>
<div>4</div>
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">Reload</a>
<div>5</div>
```

#### If still getting the issue.

- Check the website by disabling the plugins.
- Check by run site on default theme.
- Also check there may be some additional code preventing to execute the script.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put your code into my Wordpress pages. It looks like you are creating links, which you have to click on to reload.